# inserting data from primary key to foreign key

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables that have the common column this is what I used:

```
insert into smite (ID) 
  select ID from smitetournaments 
    where smite.tournament=smitetournaments.tname;
```

smite(ID) is the foreign key and ID from smitetournaments is the primary

tournament has the same values as tname but tournament has many repetetions

when I query I get

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'smite.tournament' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you looking for something like `UPDATE smite s JOIN smitetournamnts st ON s.tournament=st.tname SET s.ID=st.ID`?

Comment: it does I queried it many times to be safe

Comment: thank you joachim your code did the trick but it still left some of the values as null not sure why

Comment: Do the `tournament` values corresponding to the null rows have any matching `tname` in `smitetournaments`?

Comment: thank you I fixed it some of the tournament had over the limit value I I increased it and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess since it solved your issue it's better as an answer than a comment;

```
UPDATE smite s 
JOIN smitetournaments st 
  ON s.tournament=st.tname 
SET s.ID=st.ID
```

This update/join should match up all `tournaments` with the corresponding `tname` and update the IDs with the match.

The IDs that don't match (ie have no corresponding row in `smitetournaments` with a matching `tname`) will stay `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert smite (ID) 
select ST.ID 
FROM smitetournaments AS ST
JOIN smite AS S
  ON S.tournament=ST.tname;
```